# How to iterate over JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

The following is my JSON data in a `div`:

```
[{"Identifier":"1","Label":"10 Day","Categories":"Standard","UpdatedBy":"Lno","UpdatedAt":"01-02-2013","RefId":"0","ComType":"1","Cs":["944"],"AM":"Error Message","Message":"asdfasdf","Combiner":[{"uniqueID":"1","type":"7","rule":""}]}]
```

I am accessing it through a JS object:

```
var myArrayVar=JSON.parse(document.getElementById("populateDT").innerHTML);
```

I want to iterate over this JS object. The following is my code, but it doesn't access my key/value fields:

```
for(var i=0; i<=myArrayVar.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j<=myArrayVar.Combiner.length; j++){
        var sessionUniqueId= myArrayVar.Combiner[j].uniqueID;
        alert(sessionUniqueId);
        var sessionType=myArrayVar.Combiner[j].type;
        alert(sessionType);
        var sessionRule=myArrayVar.Combiner[j].rule;
        alert(sessionRule);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArrayVar.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < myArrayVar[i].Combiner.length; j++) {
        var sessionUniqueId = myArrayVar[i].Combiner[j].uniqueID;
        alert(sessionUniqueId);
        var sessionType = myArrayVar[i].Combiner[j].type;
        alert(sessionType);
        var sessionRule = myArrayVar[i].Combiner[j].rule;
        alert(sessionRule);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You never use `i`. You need it to access the current array element, for example:

```
for(var j=0; j<=myArrayVar[i].Combiner.length; j++){
```

`myArrayVar` is your array, `myArrayVar[i]` is the `i`-th element in that array and `myArrayVar[i].Combiner` is the combiner (array) property of the `i`-th element.

You'll make it yourself a lot easier if you give the current element a name as well. (You probably want to come up with a less generic name such as `current` though.)

```
for(var i=0; i<myArrayVar.length;i++){
    var current=myArrayVar[i];
    for(var j=0; j<current.Combiner.length; j++){
        var sessionUniqueId=current.Combiner[j].uniqueID;
        alert(sessionUniqueId);
        var sessionType=current.Combiner[j].type;
        alert(sessionType);
        var sessionRule=current.Combiner[j].rule;
        alert(sessionRule);
    }
}
```

Also, `i` cannot equal `myArrayVar.length` as that index is already out of bounds. Your loop condition should have `<` instead of `<=`.

Answer (score 2):

You have an array with one element. That element is in `myArrayVar[0]` and it is an object. To iterate over the object use a [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop.

```
var myObj = myArrayVar[0];
for(var key in myObj){
    var value = myObj[key];
    console.log(key, value);
}
```

You should also use [console.log](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) for debugging. It will show you more information about objects than alert can.

Comment: Could the downvoter please let me know what to fix in my answer?

Comment: how can you be so sure that it will always be only one element

Comment: @Ankit I can't be sure, but I can be pretty sure. A lot of APIs will return an array as a result set even when there is only ever going to be one result. I think that the OP would've shown JSON with more than one element in the array if that were possible.

Comment: Yes there could be more the one element in the array. But I think I was going wrong on myArrayVar, where else it should have been myArrayVar[0]., will try this . Thanks for the help , @Paulpro

Answer (score 1):

Try using "<" instead of "<=" in the for loops, and "myArrayVar[i].Combiner" instead of "myArrayVar.Combiner".

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems I see. First, your `i` and `j` variables go one spot too far. They should be using `<` instead of `<=`.

Secondly, you're declaring variables inside the loop. That's fine, but JavaScript isn't block scoped, so you really end up with the same three variables overwriting each other as many times as there are items in the list. Your example data only has one item so you probably won't notice the overwriting problem just yet–but once you have multiple items in the list it could be a problem.